# Display cyclic <div> tags in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have many div tags.
I am trying  to display only one  tag at a time for 10 seconds.

That is, when div1 is being displayed, div2,div3..divn must be hidden, after 10 seconds div2 has to be displayed for 10 seconds and other div tags has to be hidden and so on.
Its a kind of cyclic manner.

Kindly help.

Check out the sample html here:

```
<html>

<head>
......
.......
</head>

<body>

<div id="div1">
........
......

</div>


<div id="div2">
........
......

</div>
..
..

<div id="divn">
........
......

</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Regards,
abk

Comment: Use the jQuery cycle plugin: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work: http://jsfiddle.net/Z5uMV/

```
var current = 1;
function cycle() {
    $('#div' + current).fadeOut(function() {
        current++;
        if(current > 10) current = 1;
        $('#div' + current).fadeIn(function() {
            setTimeout(cycle, 10000);
        }
    });
}

cycle(); // start it
```

Comment: @sdespont The above code goes back to the first DIV once all are shown.

Comment: Oh right. My mistake. But you should replace number 10 with $('[id^=div]').length

Comment: @sdespont - Yes, this was just sample logic.

Comment: @techfoobar: I don't know why its still not working for me :(

Comment: @abk07 - Make sure the above code is executed only after the DOM is ready. i.e. inside `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`

Comment: @techfoobar: My div tag contains iframes, will it work? and yes its being executed only after the DOM is ready

Comment: @abk07 - Yes, it should (as long as all the DIVs are in the one frame) + you have to execute it inside the DOM ready event of that particular frame.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/CcVwW/)**

```
var myVar=setInterval(function(){myTimer()},1000);
var index=1;
totalDivs = $('[id^=div]').length;
 $('[id^=div]').hide();
function myTimer()
{
     $('[id^=div]').hide();
     $('#div'+ index++).show(); 
     if(index >  totalDivs)
       index = 0;
}
```

Comment: You certainly mean setInterval

Comment: This will fail after `#div10`. You need to reset the index somewhen.